# Fit 2 video clips in iMovie side by side without cropping

Tags: macos, imovie

When using iMovie's side-by-side feature, it cropped the clips automatically by default.  How do we make it to fit the clips into the final clip without cropping any parts of the images?

Clip1:
[image: Clip 1]

Clip2:
[image: Clip 2]

iMovie resulted:
[image: Side-by-side cropped]

Desired result:
[image: Side-by-side]

Answer (score 4):

With the Video overlay settings set to Side By Side, you should see the Cropping be activated. Click Cropping, then set the style to Crop to Fill and extend the crop to be the entire size of your input video. Repeat this step for the other video clip.

---

1. Add one of the clips to the timeline and drag the other clip above the existing clip in the timeline.
2. Go to Adjust → Video overlay settings, set the video overlay style to Side by Side and the side for the current clip.

   [image]
3. Go to Adjust → Cropping and set the cropping style to Crop to Fill

   [image]
4. Drag the bounds box to the edges of the selected clip.
5. Repeat the previous two steps for the other clip.

Comment: I follow your steps but at 3 it stops showing me the split screen. If I go back to Video overlay settings, it shows it to me but cropped (/Fit, _not_ Crop to Fill). Crop to Fill only seems to have effect when split screen is not active.

Comment: The Crop to Fill option doesn't seem to help me.  My videos still gets cut off when I go back to the "Video Overlap Settings".

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Key What happens when you try? There’s not enough detail to go on there

Comment: @grg "Crop to fill" doesn't do what the OP asked for. It still results in one of the videos being incorrectly cropped/zoomed in. Ultimately the only thing that worked for me was using "Picture in Picture" and allowing for enough room in one of the videos to overlay the second video.

Comment: @Keyan Did you do step 5? If it worked for one video I don't know why it wouldn't work for the other. Is one video the wrong aspect ratio?

Comment: Yes I did it for both videos. One video would always be shown at full size while the other would not, regardless of the above steps.

I appreciate your solution and I hope it works for others. My comment was not to criticize you, I was only trying to let others know that if your solution doesn't work that it isn't just them.

Comment: @Keyan No problem I understand, I just want to try to figure it out so I can make the answer better for you and others too! I’m not sure what the problem is though, maybe someone else will see this and know the answer.